# How can we analyze everything an application does in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, query, monitoring

I'm not a DBA (yet) but this seems a DBA-type question rather than a programming question.

I've been asked:

- Which queries are called most frequently?
- How many times are they called during a normal project?
- How long do they take to execute
- Are we able to extract an execution plan from SQL to show how it currently runs?
- Are there any potential errors in our SQL (unacceptable dirty reads, etc.)?
- Which tables are most frequently written to?
- Which tables are most frequently read from?
- How many rows do those tables normally contain for an average project?

This is complicated by the need to run in live environments.
The desire seems to be to automate some maintenance process that will fix whatever we discover, and provide input to development to stop them doing bad things.

My first thought was - recruit a DBA, probably a consultant.

Then the sheer scale of what is being asked for struck me. A project may span several months, with one SQL Server and many application servers sharing tasks between them. The data volume of this output will be immense, as will the performance overhead of monitoring every query being executed.

Are there any recommended tools for this kind of analysis?

Comment: This is likely to be closed as a shopping list question, since the real answer (aside from hiring a young and handsome consult with reasonable rates like myself) would be to get a third party monitoring tool that answers those questions.

Comment: Erik is right, and it's a good thing. You don't want someone recommending a tool that *may* or *may not* solve your problems, *may* or *may not* fall within your budget, *may* or *may not* be intuitive enough for you to use, etc, etc. There's too many variables to actually help you with that kind of question. Instead, the right thing to do is push you in a helpful direction which is what Erik said: 1. Hire a consultant, even if for the short-term to get their feedback on what your biggest issues are, and their recommendations on what tools to use, and 2. Look into SQL Server Monitoring tools.

Answer (score 5):

While this initially looks like multiple questions, you do boil it down to "Are there any recommended tools for this kind of analysis?". And the answer there is "yes". Cue outro music, roll credits.

On the off chance you wanted more detail, the answer is "it depends". What's your budget, both for purchasing tools (if necessary) and dedicating employee hours to learning, configuring, maintaining, and monitoring that software (absolutely necessary)? Are all of your examples equally important, and is it important to the business objective that a single tool answers them all or at least collates and presents the answers in a single output? Are the consumers of this information a team of developers who will individually tackle "their" issues, or leads identifying and assigning pain points, or managers prioritizing allocation of resources, or powerpoint presentations to show stakeholders How Line Go Up?

There are many tools along a number of spectra such as price, polish, flexibility, community support, and so on. I don't know why you think the data volume would be immense-- most tools to do the sort of things you describe are are 90% filtering and aggregating from standard logs, plus 10% configuration and metadata. Massive output is usually a result of people setting up installations in advance to answer every conceivable question anyone could ever ask, which might sound good in the pitch phase but merely creates a differently formatted undifferentiated pile of indecipherable data. Similarly, "performance overhead of monitoring every query" should not be a concern for the tasks you describe, since that's also available from reading log output. Your server is already keeping tabs on open threads and running processes, and any tool will leverage that.

From the context of your question, I'm inferring that your company does not have a dedicated data team. If so, narrow focus is your friend. Find the most important questions to answer, like "what are the biggest bottlenecks for frequently-run customer facing queries?". Search for a tool, or a built-in SQL monitoring process, or a publicly available script like Brent Ozar's sp_BlitzCache that answers that specific question, and set up a process around that: alert emails, or SSRS reports, or whatever fits the circumstances for getting the information to the people who can make decisions based on it. This is an achievable short-term goal for a single developer who is not a database expert. Then answer the next most important question, and add that output to your process. Once the business side of that process has matured and there are multiple people accustomed to receiving and acting upon the information, that might be the time to consider a third-party tool.

Most third-party monitoring tools are to one extent or another advanced versions of this process, and many of them are great. But it sounds like your environment doesn't currently have the resources or expertise to make good use of these tools, which means getting them set up could be a lengthy and frustrating process that ends in a lot of very pretty screens that remain mostly indecipherable and go largely ignored. In short, monitoring tools are a lot like the power tools one finds at a hardware store: powerful, convenient, and every experienced user has their favorites for reasons they will explain for hours on end. But they don't replace expertise, and if the user doesn't have a pretty good idea how to accomplish the same thing with manual tools, then the power versions are a swift and expensive path to self-inflicted injury.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer somewhat alludes to this, but I suggest that you're presenting an X-Y Problem™. Suppose you somehow got all your bullet points answered; what will the person(s), by whom you "have been asked", will do with the answers? What is the actual problem you/they are trying to solve?

Do you feel you are paying too much for cloud infrastructure and want to know how much you can scale it down? Is there a particular business function that does not perform as it should? Do you want to project how much disk space you will be using next year?

Determine the most important root problem you want solved, then the question of the most appropriate tools will be much easier to answer.